# Leap Motion + Pygame | Displaying text in window

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, pygame

I'm trying to use the pygame library with the Leap Motion. I'm trying to display some of the data from the Leap Motion in my window, however when I try to retrieve a variable from my `SampleListener` class and feed it into my `Main` method, I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'avg_pos'

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about Class > Method > Variable structure?

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
import Leap, sys, pygame

#Window 
windowWidth = 800
windowHeight = 600

#Leap Motion Settings
class SampleListener(Leap.Listener):

    def on_init(self, controller):
        print "Initialized"

    def on_connect(self, controller):
        print "Connected"

    def on_disconnect(self, controller):
        # Note: not dispatched when running in a debugger.
        print "Disconnected"

    def on_exit(self, controller):
        print "Exited"

    def on_frame(self, controller):
        # Get the most recent frame and report some basic information
            if not self.frame.hands.empty:
                # Get the first hand
                hand = self.frame.hands[0]

                # Check if the hand has any fingers
                fingers = hand.fingers
                if not fingers.empty:
                    # Calculate the hand's average finger tip position
                    avg_pos = Leap.Vector()
                    for finger in fingers:
                        avg_pos += finger.tip_position
                    avg_pos /= len(fingers)
                    print "Hand has %d fingers, average finger tip position: %s" % (
                          len(fingers), avg_pos)

#Application Loop
def main():
    pygame.init()
    window = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth,windowHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption("TEST123")

    #Surface 
    background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
    background = background.convert()
    background.fill ((50,0,80))

    if pygame.font:
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
        text = font.render("%s" % SampleListener.on_frame.len(fingers), 1, (255, 255, 255))
        textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=background.get_width()/2)
        background.blit(text, textpos)

    # Create a sample listener and controller
    listener = SampleListener()
    controller = Leap.Controller()

    # Have the sample listener receive events from the controller
    controller.add_listener(listener)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        #Handle Input Events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
                # Remove the sample listener when done
                controller.remove_listener(listener)

        window.blit(background, (0,0))
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: Here is the full traceback error -

```
Line 53, in main
    text = font.render("%s" % SampleListener.on_frame.avg_pos, 1, (255, 255, 255))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'avg_pos'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Never seen the Leap Motion before - looks pretty amazing! I can't see anything in the `on_frame` method that should be causing that error... are you able to edit the question and paste more of the stack trace and/or point out which line is causing the exception?

Comment: Can you post the full Traceback message?

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems like it might be that pygame.font is not a boolean, therefore can not be used in an if statement.
(
quote:

```
def main():
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth,windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST123")

#Surface 
background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill ((50,0,80))

if pygame.font: \\ HERE   <---
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
    text = font.render("%s" % SampleListener.on_frame.len(fingers), 1, (255, 255, 255))
    textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=background.get_width()/2)
    background.blit(text, textpos)
```

)

Comment: I think the if statement is still valid because when I change the part within font.render that contains the string to something else, like "TEST" - it works when I run the program.

Comment: Maybe that's something to do with leap... I know in plain pygame it woudn't work